# regex line works in regex101, but throws an "bad character in group name" in code (inside If clause)

Tags: python, regex, regex-group

Im trying to parse a combat log from a game. My solution to check for "(Critical)" caused some issues.

lookahead conditional seemed to be the only way to catch data even if "(Critical)" is not present. This worked in regex101

```py
var = re.compile("(?P<hour>\d{2}):(?P<min>\d{2}):(?P<sec>\d{2}):(?P<milsec>\d{3}) (\[Loot] Gained (?P<xp>\S+) XP?|\[Loot] Item Acquired: (?P<loot>.*)|\[Loot] Gained (?P<dram>\S+) Dram?|\[Loot] Earned (?P<reputation>\S+) Reputation?|\[Combat] (?P<dude_hurt>.+) took (?P<damages>\S+) damage from (?P<damage_dealer>[\S]+)(?(?=.) (?P<crit>\(Critical\))|))")
```

re.error: bad character in group name `?=.` at position 303

which is the last part:  `(?(?=.) (?P<crit>\(Critical\))|))")`

### Sample data:

```
19:59:16:394 [Combat] player1 took 4301 damage from Stafrusher(47)

19:59:16:547 [Combat] Stafrage(45) took 12049 damage from player2

19:59:17:060 [Combat] Stafrage(45) took 8621 damage from player3 (Critical)

19:59:17:375 [Combat] Stafrage(45) took 7931 damage from player2 (Critical)
```

Comment: On the left-hand column, make sure you've checked the "Python" flavor

Comment: @Zero Yeah, I fixed it for you. If you tried something at regex101 then why don't you share what you've tried by providing a link? It's better to show us rather than having us guess at what you messed up.

Comment: JETM was correct, I dint use the "Python" flavor. so my regex is incorrect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you take a look at the regex on regex101, **when switched to python dialect** it shows a pattern error `incomplete group structure` right where you get your error

the regex with error in python dialect: https://regex101.com/r/vlHCCO/2

you probably wanted a non-matching group there, which needs a missing `:`

EDIT: i re-read your question, and i noticed that you probably want to only match lines with critical. heres the regex for that.

fixed regex: https://regex101.com/r/vlHCCO/4

further than that, do you really need to group each (time?) number seperately when the same thing could be done easier using one group and `"19:59:16:547".split(":")` -> `["19", "59", "16" "547"]`

Comment: You were correct the first time. I want to catch all the lines, and also see which attack is a crit or not. The best situation would be that it returned boolean True instead of "(Critical)" inside the crit group, but I can easily do that in code instead.

Comment: @Zero sorry about that, it wasnt very clear. If you want to match one or zero occurences of a group, using a ? does that.